# Sequence purchases in a table where the sequence is unique to the purchaser

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm looking at a table as follows:

```
Idx | CustID |Item       | Date
________________________________
1   | 1      | Black Ink | 2023-01-01
2   | 2      | Red Ink   | 2023-01-21
3   | 1      | Black Ink | 2023-01-12
4   | 2      | Red ink   | 2023-02-14
```

What I'm trying to do is to sequence the purchases by customer with a unique sequence per customer as follows:

```
Idx | CustID |Item       | Date       | Sequence
_________________________________________________
1   | 1      | Black Ink | 2023-01-01 | 1
3   | 1      | Black Ink | 2023-01-12 | 2
2   | 2      | Red Ink   | 2023-01-21 | 1
4   | 2      | Red ink   | 2023-02-14 | 2
```

How do I add the 'Sequence' column? I've tried using a sub-select statement with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustID, Item)` but it just sequences the entire table like `Idx`.

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve. You use a sequence column but the data are not sequential, that odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `PARTITION BY` clause to your `ROW_NUMBER()` to start numbering againg for new `CustID`

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY Item) rn
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: PARTITION !!! Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried using a sub-select statement with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustID, Item)` but it just sequences the entire table like `Idx`.

Your `row_number()` needs a `partition by` clause, so that each customer gets its own iterator. So something like:

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by custid order by idx) seq
from mytable t
```

Depending on your actual use case, you might want to consider ordering by `date` rather than by `idx`. Also if there may be ties, then `rank()` is more relevant than `row_number()`.